# makeLenses on data with constraint (DatatypeContexts)

Tags: haskell, lenses

Can I use the `makeLenses` template on a data type with constraints and if so, how? I'd like to do so without reading all about [Template Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell).

In GHC I have this example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances, NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
module Main (main) where

import Control.Lens
import Control.Monad.Reader  -- mtl

class Class1 a where
    someThing :: a  -- just some filler

instance (Num a) => Class1 a where
    someThing = 3

data (Class1 a) => Foo a = Foo { _field1 :: a }

makeLenses ''Foo

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn . show $ runReader (view field1) $ Foo { _field1 = 5 }
```

This produces this compile error:

```
Could not deduce (Num a1) arising from a use of ‘Foo’
from the context (Profunctor p, Functor f)
  bound by the type signature for
             field1 :: (Profunctor p, Functor f) =>
                       p a (f a1) -> p (Foo a) (f (Foo a1))
  at src/main.hs:58:1-16
Possible fix:
  add (Num a1) to the context of
    the type signature for
      field1 :: (Profunctor p, Functor f) =>
                p a (f a1) -> p (Foo a) (f (Foo a1))
In the second argument of ‘iso’, namely ‘Foo’
In the expression: iso (\ (Foo x_a3NK) -> x_a3NK) Foo
In an equation for ‘field1’:
    field1 = iso (\ (Foo x_a3NK) -> x_a3NK) Foo
```

So I think it generated:

```
field1 :: Lens' (Foo a) a
```

I've also tried `makeFields` and `makeClassy`, to no avail.

I know I could work around this with:

```
field1 :: (Class1 a) => Lens' (Foo a) a
field1 = lens _field1 (\ foo val -> Foo { _field1 = val })
```

But is there a way to do it with `makeLenses` or Template Haskell?

I'm using GHC version 7.8.4, and `lens` version 4.8.

(Note: I know there have been similar questions about makeLenses, but I still couldn't get it to work. I'm a beginner at haskell.)

Comment: What GHC version is this, and what `lens` version? Always include this info.

Comment: @dfeuer GHC version 7.8.4, and `lens` version 4.8.

Comment: You are using DatatypeContexts, a deprecated extension which has no merit, so I don't think you can expect support for it in the lens deriving machinery.

Comment: @user2407038, the reason I asked about the version is that `DatatypeContexts` doesn't appear in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, I believe, is that datatype contexts are a somewhat broken feature. You probably mean to use a GADT:

```
{-# Language GADTs #-}

data Foo a where
  Foo :: Class1 a => a -> Foo a
```

I'm not sure how to get the record syntax in there with the class constraint.

Unfortunately, as Ørjan Johansen [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134349/makelenses-on-data-with-constraint/29134651?noredirect=1#comment46494930_29134651), you will immediately run into trouble making the lenses automatically because of the existential type. But you should, I believe be able to write them by hand, whereas the datatype context would never ever have worked.

Comment: Unfortunately a GADT hits straight at one of [my previous answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28145369/makelenses-for-gadts-haskell/28145814#28145814) which I have a small hunch the OP already found...

Comment: @Ørjan Johansen I came across that one indeed.

Comment: In record syntax:
`data Foo a where
    Foo :: Class1 a => { _field1 :: a } -> Foo a`

Details on GADT: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html#gadt

Comment: @timdiels, thanks. I read that page, but got the colons confused in the GADT record syntax and decided to just throw up my hands. I've used GADTs, and I've used records, but I've never used them together.